# Soundcard with realtime microphone monitoring

Tags: windows, audio, sound-card, microphone, audio-recording

I have a soundcard (Audigy 2ZS), which is very old and very poorly supported in modern Windows OSes, but this sound card has very important feature - when I use microphone, I can hear my own voice through the headphones with absolutely NO delay (i.e. I can monitor my voice in realtime) - as opposed to standard windows feature of "playback of recording device", which creates a delay of ~1 second, which is unacceptable.

Is there a way to eliminate that delay in standard windows functionality?

Answer (score 1):

ADA-17 USB - HQ MINI AUDIO Soundcard

No driver needed!

Direct monitoring:

Press Windows+R!

Type: "mmsys.cpl" - Press ENTER!

Playback devices - USB Advanced Audio Device - Double Click!

Levels Panel WOW!!!! Direct monitoring!!!

Sorry - Bad English...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

You're really looking for a specific capability - called direct monitoring, which I've seen in some external cards. My M-audio Fast Track has that feature, and creative cards that support [ASIO 2.0](http://support.creative.com/kb/ShowArticle.aspx?sid=7358) - seem to typically support it as well.

Find a card with direct monitoring and you should be fine.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer, but the main problem is in *finding* such sound card. Googling "direct monitoring sound card" didn't help.